# Are glyphs always fully visible if `line-height` = `font-size`?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

When using web fonts, are glyphs always fully visible if `line-height` = `font-size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, glyphs may extend above (and below) the top and the bottom of the font (the conceptual lines that define the height of the font). A simple example is the letter “Å” in the Verdana font. (Not a web font, but a web font can be of any design.)

Comment: The problem is that `line-height` clips. I.e. there seems to be no way to arbitrarily reduce line distance without clipping glyphs, which *is* possible in many typesetting systems.